# How to manage the node modules dependencies if you have some custom code changes in the dependencies?

Tags: npm, npm-install, react-native

I am working on a react-native mobile project for Android and iOS. I am facing a problem where I had to change a NavigationReactGateway.java inside node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/react/ to fix a crash on my application.

Now my question is how am I supposed to maintain these dependencies in package.json? As I have people in my team who are working on the same project and I do not want them to change their local node_modules.

Is there a way to manage such scenarios where there is a bug in the dependency with npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `react-native-navigation` is open source, you can submit a pull request with your fix. In the meantime, create a fork, fix the bug there and reference the forked repo instead.

- [How to fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)
- [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)
- [Git URLs as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

(If this had **not** been open source, I have no better suggestion than have all developers do the local change. I'd love to see a better answer on that, though; I've been there.)

Comment: I did fork the code and referenced the fork. I used yarn install --flat to override the inner dependencies.